# How to order array of objects by property PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I have the following array of objects coming from a json. The idea is to sort by the observation property. How can I do this?

**My Array from objects**

```
[
    [
        "id" => "07e17609-2359-4b21-9161-6e10715eb2f1",
        "description" => "Digital Account",
        "observation" => null
    ],
    [
        "id" => "1f9a3695-dafe-46yb-9caa-7a413bedc3c9",
        "description" => "Cashback",
        "observation" => '1% cashback on all purchases using Méliuz'
    ],
    [
        "id" => "0f9a5695-dafe-46fb-9caa-7a418bedc3c9",
        "description" => "Google Pay",
        "observation" => null
    ],
];
```

**The desired sort output**

```
[
    [
        "id" => "1f9a3695-dafe-46yb-9caa-7a413bedc3c9",
        "description" => "Cashback",
        "observation" => '1% cashback on all purchases using Méliuz'
    ],
    [
        "id" => "07e17609-2359-4b21-9161-6e10715eb2f1",
        "description" => "Digital Account",
        "observation" => null
    ],
    [
        "id" => "0f9a5695-dafe-46fb-9caa-7a418bedc3c9",
        "description" => "Google Pay",
        "observation" => null
    ],
];
```

That is, if the observation field is not null, it must come first in the sort

I tried with the usert below, but it didn't work.

```
usort($this->rewards, fn($a, $b) => strcmp($a->observation, $b->observation));
```

Comment: Your JSON is not JSON. It is a piece extracted in the middle of it. Valid JSON cannot start with `"rewards":`. Also, JSON has no single-quoted string literals. Can you provide valid JSON?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is convert the JSON data to an array using `json_decode`. Then, you can sort it using `array_multisort`. Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php, specially the third example.

Comment: @trincot, I updated my quetstion only array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your `usort` callback function as follows:

```
usort($data->rewards, fn ($a, $b) =>
    is_null($a->observation) - is_null($b->observation) || 
    strcmp($a->observation, $b->observation)
);
```

This will force the `null` values to the end.

Comment: `usort` always returns a boolean value. You need to look at `$data->rewards`, which will have been sorted. That's how all PHP sorting functions work. See their documentation.